# WooCommerce, store page with Elementor works one strange

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I use WooCommerce on the site I created with Elementor Template Kit. When I scroll the store page slightly down with the mouse, it suddenly goes down to the products. Not a pleasant situation. There is no hook in that part. I couldn't find the reason.

Can you watch the video?

Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wR0OFnhryFdc7gez6udlE3HC-hotQlJb/view?usp=drive_link

This is the first time I've encountered this problem, I've checked everything but I can't find the problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.